# Action and outlet unavailable

Tags: xcode3.2

my newGame button wasnt working (it was not changing viewcontrollers" and i saw that there were some interface builder warnings

I connected an action to a button (newGame:) and files owner to the view (view outlet) and here 
in interface builder the warnings say:|

Action unavailable :

The 'touch up inside' event of 'rounded rect button' is connected to the 'newGame:' selector of the 'files owner' but 'newGame:' is no longer defined on 'l' at least i think its l it could be a capital i without the short top lines on it.

[Session started at 2011-04-16 22:46:06 +0800.]
2011-04-16 22:46:07.306 Math[40468:207] Unknown class RootViewController in Interface Builder file.

when i build i do get that error above because i refactored

tell me if u need my coding!

Comment: ita ok i found out why its not working

Comment: well ok the answer is: my mainwindow xib was not changed when refactoring

Comment: :) Nah, post it as answer, not as a comment. And then check the check mark.

Comment: cant answer my own q till 24 hrs